# How to query custom post types posts filtered by multiple custom taxonomies through a form selection

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, filters, query-posts, forms

I'm trying to create a sort of selection menu, in order to select custom posts by different custom taxonomies. I did the selection part, but I can't get to output my post and I can't understand where my mistakes are.
What I have so fare:
 - Custom post type: "corsi";
 - 5 different custom taxonomies: "prodotto", "livello", "ruolo", "stato";
 - The selection form, made as a form, with radio button input and a bit of jQuery.

**The form part**

```
  <form id="regiration_form" novalidate action="<?php echo $current_url;?>" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <h1>1</h1>
            <?php

    $prodotto_terms = get_terms( 'prodotto', array(
          'orderby'    => 'date',
          'order' => 'DESC',
          'hide_empty' => 0
        ) );
    ?>
                <?php foreach( $prodotto_terms as $term ) {
                          $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
                          echo '<input type="radio" name="prodotto" value="'.$term->slug.'">'.$term->name.'<br>';
                        }       

                    ?>

        </div>
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-info" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <h1>2</h1>
            <?php $livello_terms = get_terms( 'livello', array(
          'orderby'    => 'date',
          'order' => 'DESC',
          'hide_empty' => 0
        ) );
    ?>
                <?php foreach( $livello_terms as $term ) {
                          $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
                          echo '<input type="radio" name="livello" value="'.$term->slug.'">'.$term->name.'<br>';
                        }       

                    ?>


                    <?php $ruolo_terms = get_terms( 'ruolo', array(
          'orderby'    => 'date',
          'order' => 'DESC',
          'hide_empty' => 0
        ) );
             ?>
        </div>
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous btn btn-default" value="Previous" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-info" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <h1>3</h1>
            <?php foreach( $ruolo_terms as $term ) {
                          $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
                          echo '<input type="radio" name="ruolo" value="'.$term->slug.'">'.$term->name.'<br>';
                        }       

                    ?>

                            <?php $stato_terms = get_terms( 'stato', array(
          'orderby'    => 'date',
          'order' => 'DESC',
          'hide_empty' => 0
        ) );
            ?>
                    </div>
                    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous btn btn-default" value="Previous" />
                    <input type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-info" value="Next" />
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h1>4</h1>
                        <?php foreach( $stato_terms as $term ) {
                          $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
                          echo '<input type="radio" name="stato" value="'.$term->slug.'">'.$term->name.'<br>';
                        }       

                    ?>

                    </div>
                    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous btn btn-default" value="Previous" />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit btn btn-success" value="Submit" />
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

**And this how I tried to output the posts, but nothing is showing up :/**

```
 <?php    
                                if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
                                    { 

                                       $prodotto = $_POST["prodotto"];       
                                       $livello = $_POST["livello"];       
                                       $ruolo = $_POST["ruolo"];       
                                       $stato = $_POST["stato"]; 


                                    $soluzioni = new WP_Query( array( 
                                      'post_type' => 'corsi',
                                      'posts_per_page' => -1,
                                      'orderby' => 'title',
                                      'order'   => 'ASC',
                                      'paged' => $paged,
                                      'tax_query' => array(
                                        'relation' => 'AND',
                                         array(
                                           'taxonomy' => 'prodotto',
                                           'field' => 'slug',
                                           'terms' => $prodotto 
                                         ),
                                         array(
                                           'taxonomy' => 'livello',
                                           'field' => 'slug',
                                           'terms' => $livello
                                         )
                                      ) ) );


                                        if ( $soluzioni->have_posts() ) {
                                            echo '<ul>';
                                            while ( $soluzioni->have_posts() ) {
                                                $soluzioni->the_post();
                                                echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
                                            }
                                            echo '</ul>';

                                            wp_reset_postdata();
                                        } else {
                                            // no posts found
                                        }


                                                        } ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance, have a nice day :)

Lisa

Comment: Have you tried removing parameters from your query to see which ones are stopping it from working? And have you verified that all the data is indeed making it through correctly?

Comment: Hi Tom, I just tried and apparently the problem was the "AND" relation. Seems to work now. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: can you post that as an answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem was in the "AND" relation. Code now seems to work:

```
 <?php    
     if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
                { 
                    $prodotto = $_POST["prodotto"];       
                    $livello = $_POST["livello"];       
                    $ruolo = $_POST["ruolo"];       
                    $stato = $_POST["stato"]; 



                    $args = array( 
                            'post_type' => 'corsi',
                            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            'orderby' => 'title',
                            'order'   => 'ASC',
                            'tax_query' => array(

                                array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'prodotto',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms' => $prodotto,
                                         ),
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'livello',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms' => $livello,
                                         ),
                                 array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'ruolo',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms' => $ruolo,
                                         ),
                              array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'stato',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms' => $stato,
                                         ),


                                      ) 
                                    );
                    $soluzioni = new WP_Query($args);

                                if ( $soluzioni->have_posts() ) {
                                        echo '<ul>';
                                            while ( $soluzioni->have_posts() ) {
                                                $soluzioni->the_post();
                                                                    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
                                                                            }
                                                        echo '</ul>';

                                                            wp_reset_postdata();
                                                                } else 
                                                                    {
                                                                           echo '<br/> OPPALLA no post';
                                                                    }




                             }
```